# Is there any way to create a custom MVC Razor element like "text"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I want to create a custom razor tag like `<text></text>` to decide what to do with the html code inside of it. Is there any way to create razor elements like `<text></text>` element and add it to the razor engine?

**I don't want to create any HtmlHelpers for this.**

For Examle:

```
<WYSYWIG>
Hello There!
</WYSYWIG>
```

or

```
<WeatherChart City="NY">
</WeatherChart>
```

**Explanation:**

Well the idea is to have server tags to be translated (Parsed) to html codes by the attributes given to them. This kind of codes helps junior developers not to be involved with the complexity of controls.

Comment: Wouldn't this make invalid HTML markup? Perhaps further clarification on if you want to make custom HTML or use a DisplayTemplate?

Comment: These are custom html tags. I don't understand how this could have anything to do with Razor engine. It would be more helpful if you could explain what exactly you want to do.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem (i.e. please tell us what you are trying to achieve!)

Comment: Well the idea is to have server tags to be translated to html codes by the attributes given to them. This kind of codes helps junior developers not to be involved with the complexity of controls.

Comment: @HiradNikoo: Long story short, you'd be looking at implementing your own System.Web.Razor.dll (and subsequently the `System.Web.Razor.Parser.HtmlMarkupParser`)

Comment: @BradChristie: Your comment sounds like the answer. Could you please explain more about it as an Answer block so it could be marked as the correct answer?

Comment: I seems like you don't have a grasp on how MVC literally functions because you used the word *control* like WebForms.  MVC *controls* are Templates and are not instantiated by using tags. Please read [Brad Wilsons Blog about Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).  Building out templates allow serperates developers from needing to know how to display/edit values.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't know if you understood my question or not. I think if you look at the other answers you can get a clear picture of what was my question and just down grading my question is not fair. My question was based on what <text></text> does in razor engine. Please answer the question rather than down grading it to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you are describing is to create display or editor templates.  You can then define a template for a model and use it with `@Html.DisplayFor()` in the view.

Here is a good blog post to get you started [aspnet mvc display and editor templates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) and a quick overview of the structure below.

**Example**

#### Model - WeatherChartModel.cs

```
public class WeatherChartModel 
{
}
```

#### Display template - WeatherChart.cshtml

```
<div class="weather-chart">
   // Some other stuff here
</div>
```

#### View - Index.cshtml

```
@model WeatherChartModel

@Html.DisplayForModel() // This will output the template view for the model
```

Comment: Yeah. this is not what I had in mind. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create custom element handling in razor, such as `<text>`, you'd need to implement a custom `System.Web.Razor.dll` (which is responsible for parsing the document). Specifically, the class you're looking to re-implement would be the `System.Web.Razor.Parser.HtmlMarkupParser`.

However, I don't believe this is necessary given how flexible the framework itself is. If you're looking to keep things modular, have a look at either using DisplayTemplates/EditorTemplates or consider writing your own extension method. For example, either of the following would be more ideal:

```
@* TextField is decorated with UIHint("WYSIWYG"), therefore
   calling ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/WYSIWYG.cshtml *@
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TextField)

@* WeatherField is decorated with UIHint("WeatherChart"), therefore
   calling ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/WeatherChart.cshtml *@
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.WeatherField)
```

Alternatively:

```
@* Custom extension method *@
@Html.WysiwygFor(x => x.TextField)

@* Another custom extension method *@
@Html.WeatherChartFor(x => x.WeatherField)
```